# Azure maps - change the color of a pin based on data driven styling

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I am trying to create a data driven layer style that uses a [boolean expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/data-driven-style-expressions-web-sdk#boolean-expressions), but I am not sure how to make it work.

I have a Feature shape defined.  Notice the property bag has an `assigned` property.

```
new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point([-122.3802, 47.54384]), {
    leaseNo: '928928A',
    assigned: true
}),
```

Then for the SymbolLayer the Feature is assigned to uses a style definition as...

```
iconOptions: {
    image: [
        'match',
        ['get', 'assigned'],
        ['==', 'true'], 'marker-red',
        'marker-darkblue'
    ]
}
```

It retrieves the value of the `assigned` property and returns a marker  based on whether the value is true or false.

However, it's not working, so my syntax isn't correct.  Can someone help me with the syntax to make this work?

Comment: `match` returns `string | number`, you could try `['match', ['get', 'assigned'], 1, 'marker-red', 'marker-darkblue']`, I'm not sure if they coerce the value though, it may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using `case`.

```
iconOptions: {
    image: [
        'case',
        ['get', 'assigned'], 'marker-red',
        'marker-darkblue'
    ]
}
```